# Failed to query the value of property 'packageName'

Tags: react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am running React-Native 0.63.4 and encountering the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'buildConfigPackageName'.
   > Failed to query the value of property 'packageName'.
      > java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0.0"
```

This occurs when running `npm run android`, shortly after Gradle is done configuring the app and tries to execute it.

This error occurs both when I run the command from the root folder of the project as well as from the /android/ subfolder.

I did a `gradlew clean` but it is not helping.

Edit:

If I go in my /android/ folder and run `gradlew android`, the build will complete without error.

It is only when I run `npm run android` that this error shows up.

Comment: do share build.gradle deafult cofing setting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

on the file: `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

The content began by:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.MyBusiness.MyApp"
          android:versionCode="1.0.0"
          android:versionName="1.0.0">
```

The versionCode has to be an integer: Only digits allowed. Apparently it does not matter what it is as it will increment whatever number we put.

Changing this to a number solved my problem:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.MyBusiness.MyApp"
          android:versionCode="1000"
          android:versionName="1.0.0">
```

Comment: Setting version code to random number is strongly discouraged as every next version published to Play Store should have bigger version code. Setting it to 1000 for production app would require to increase number +1 forever(1001, 1002, etc. ). There is no way to change or reset it once it is published to Play Store. If you need to set version code, good practice is to just start from number 1. Or if you have already published app, you can easily see version code of the last release from Play Store console and set version code +1 of that one.

Answer (score 17):

Here's another solution:

- It's possible the xmls:tools is missing from `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` folder. So you'll need to add that back.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.<buildname>">
```

- This should be the first line at the top of your `Manifest.xml`.

Comment: thanks a lot @Aurelien Essome, you saved my day, kudos to you <3

Comment: @JaveedIshaq, for sure my pleasure.

Comment: The same issue for Flutter Framework. `xmlns:tools` is missing when Flutter generates a new Android project

Comment: Thanks, you save my day @Relie Essom.

Comment: Setting the namespace via a source AndroidManifest.xml's package attribute is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions seem technically correct, but for me, this was caused by accidentally typing some characters in the highlighted section.

```
<application
        android<Added some extra characters by mistake>:label="My App"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
...
```

> This is not a technical solution, but may help someone who stumbles into this error through similar mistakes.