# RN Error :> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig FAILED

Tags: react-native

I have a problem building a RN project in android I run: `yarn android` and that's what I face: [image]

I tried to clean the gradle: `./gradlew clean` I also tried to delete the build in android: `rm -rf android/app/build` but none of these worked for me.

Any clue what's the problem or maybe solution?

Comment: Seems like there is a problem parsing your AndroidManifest.xml.
Check the properties package in the tag <manifest> if it's set correctly.
Check also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65244902/9899604 , might help

Comment: @Onlinogame I have seen this post before, I added the `android:versionCode="1000"`, but it did not work for me, however you said that the problem in the `AndroidManifest.xml ` so I could track the problem and fix it --- and the problem was `tools:node="remove" ` in this permission  `<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" /> ` after I removed  `tools:node="remove" `  it worked, thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

try to open android folder on your project in android studio app, gradle will update automatically

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you received a suggestion for resolving an issue. To implement the solution, please navigate to the following directory

> `android > app > src > main`

In this folder, you will find the file `AndroidManifest.xml`. Within this file, you may find permissions that contain the attribute `tools:node="remove"`. Please remove this attribute from the permission(s) as shown below:

From this

```
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

to this

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />`

This should resolve the problem you are facing.